# Concatenate column values when header is Matching from multiple files

Tags: perl, unix, join, awk, sed

there can be n number of columns but the number of columns and header name will remain same in all 3 files. Files are tab Delimited.

a.txt

```
Name  9/1   9/2
X   1   7
y   2   8
z   3   9
a   4   10
b   5   11
c   6   12
```

b.xt

```
Name  9/1   9/2
X   13  19
y   14  20
z   15  21
a   16  22
b   17  23
c   18  24
```

c.txt

```
Name  9/1   9/2
X   25  31
y   26  32
z   27  33
a   28  34
b   29  35
c   30  36
```

required output

```
Name  9/1   9/2
X   1/13/25 7/19/31
y   2/14/26 8/20/32
z   3/15/27 9/21/33
a   4/16/28 10/22/34
b   5/17/29 11/23/35
c   6/16/30 12/24/36
```

I Want to merge all three file on the basis of matching header and if values are same in the row then print one value 
and if different then concatenate values from all three files under that column. like in file a.txt,b.txt,c.txt, 
row 2 has same value under column name "NAME" so print only X but column "9/1" has different values so print one header " 9/1" and under it print all values from three files e.g. 1/13/25.

tried below

```
join <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt) <(sort c.txt) >out.txt
```

but it is printing all the rows from file a then starting file b then c 
same thing with this

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} ($1 in a){ print $0, a[$1]}' a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ZIm will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reads a line from all files at a time and joins the same field from each, for any number of files and columns. The first field of each line  across all files is assumed the same. (Submit sorted files.)

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;

# Implicit filehandles. Use readline() to read from them, not <>
my @fh = map { open my $fh, '<', $_  or die "Can't open $_: $!"; $fh } @ARGV;

while (1) 
{ 
    # Read a line from all files. Exit loop if any is undefined
    my @line = map { scalar readline $_ } @fh;
    last if  grep { not defined $line[$_] } 0..$#line;
    # Print first line (header) from one file, skip further processing
    if ($. == 1) { 
        print $line[0];
        next;
    }   

    # Get the first column from one file, assumed the same for all  
    my @out_line = (split ' ', $line[0])[0];
    # Join same column from all files with '/', for all columns
    for my $i (1..$#line) {
        push @out_line, join '/', map { (split)[$i] } @line;
    }   
    print "@out_line\n";
}
```

Produces the required output with `script.pl a.txt b.txt c.txt`, given sorted input files.

Comments. Let me know if fuller explanations would be helpful.

- Assumes the same first column. Exits as soon as one file is exhausted
- Uses "*implicit filehandles*" -- read from it via `readline`, not `<>` *operator*. See [in perlfaq5](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-use-a-filehandle-indirectly%3F)
- The `scalar readline $_` forces scalar context so that one line is read
- Leaves the newline. To remove it add `chomp(@lines)`, after `last if ...`
- The first two lines can be used to form the `while (...)` condition

---

*Original post, condensed. Left here for possible usefulness of discussion of `join`*

This gets you almost there with `join`, and completes the job with Perl.

First, `join` takes only two files at the time.  So you can run it with the first two, then run it with the resulting file and the last one. We also need to tell it how to format output.  This is done with its `-o` option, 
which allows us to list the elements of an output line as `FileN.fieldN, ...`

What you need is: `1.1` `1.2` `2.2` `1.3` `2.3` -- Fields 1,2 from File 1 then 2 from 2, etc.

```
join -o 1.1,1.2,2.2,1.3,2.3 a.txt b.txt  > ab.txt
```

File `ab.txt` has a different format so the `-o` format of lines changes for the next step

```
join -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.2,1.4,1.5,2.3 ab.txt c.txt  > abc.txt
```

This has two glitches -- headers are joined, fields merged with space. Fix with Perl one-liners.

Collect in a bash script. A working sketch, to run as `script.sh a.txt b.txt c.txt`

```
#!/bin/bash

join -o 1.1,1.2,2.2,1.3,2.3         $1     $2  > tmp.$$
join -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.2,1.4,1.5,2.3 tmp.$$ $3  > abc.txt

# Remove extra fields in the header    
perl -i -wpe '$.==1 && s{(\d/\d) \1 \1}{$1}g'  abc.txt

# Replace space with `/` between every three numbers
perl -i -wpe 's{(\d+) (\d+) (\d+)}{$1/$2/$3}g' abc.txt

rm -f tmp.$$
```

Please choose temporary names more carefully and add error checking. The output `abc.txt`

```
Name 9/1 9/2
X 1/13/25 7/19/31
y 2/14/26 8/20/32
...
```

Comment: @Zim ...thank you very much ...each file has n number of columns for example 32 columns in files a 32 columns in file b and 32 columns in file c. column header and column number will remain same in each file.how can I get the desired result.

Comment: @Neha  I updated the answer, with a script at the beginning. It joins same fields in each line of all files, so second fields in the same line of all files are joined (with `/`), then third, etc. It works for any number of columns, and any number of files.

Comment: @Neha Great :) A script should be a solid solution, easy to tweak if what you need to do changes. Please let me know if questions pop up.

Answer (score 2):

The output order is Gnu awk default:

```
$ cat > combine.txt 
FNR==NR {
    a[$1]=$2                                # gather the 2 dates in variables
    b[$1]=$3
    next
} 
FNR>1 && ($1 in a) {
    a[$1]=a[$1] "/" $2
    b[$1]=b[$1] "/" $3
} 
END {                                       # print built up variables in the end
    # PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"  # output order control with this
                                            # in Gnu awk 
    for(i in a) print i, a[i], b[i]
}
```

Test it:

```
$ awk -f comnine.awk a.txt b.txt c.txt
y 2/14/26 8/20/32
z 3/15/27 9/21/33
a 4/16/28 10/22/34
b 5/17/29 11/23/35
c 6/18/30 12/24/36
X 1/13/25 7/19/31
Name 9/1 9/2
```

Revised version in Gnu awk that *should* support more than 2 fields of data. I only tested with the data you provided. Let me know if it works and I delete the original limited version.

```
FNR==NR {
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
        a[$1][i]=$i
    next
}
FNR>1 && ($1 in a) {
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
        a[$1][i]=a[$1][i] "/" $i
}
END {                                       # print built up variables in the end                                                                              
    # PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"  # output order control with this    
                                            # in Gnu awk                        
    for(i in a) {
        printf "%s", i OFS
        for(j=2;j<=NF;j++)
            printf "%s", a[i][j] (j<NF?OFS:ORS)
    }
}
```

As you had tagget `join` also I decided to give it a try:

```
$ join -o 1.1 1.2 2.2 2.4 1.3 2.3 2.5 a.txt <(join b.txt c.txt) | sed 's/ /\//g2; s/\// /3'
Name 9/1/9 1/9/1/9/2/9/2/9/2
X 1/13/25 7/19/31
y 2/14/26 8/20/32
z 3/15/27 9/21/33
a 4/16/28 10/22/34
b 5/17/29 11/23/35
c 6/18/30 12/24/36
```

ie. first join `b.txt` and `c.txt` and join that result with `a.txt`. `sed` is used for output control on replacing some of the spaces with `/`. `man join` reveals `--header` switch but it did not want to cooperate with me on this.

Comment: Thank you @James ...Awk solution worked for two columns but each file has n number of columns for example 32 columns in files a 32 columns in file b and 32 columns in file c. column header and column number will remain same in each file.how can I get the desired result.

Comment: Introduced a revised version.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed & bash):

For the example given (two columns):

```
sed -sr '1d;s#(.*\t)(.*)\t(.*)#/^\1/s@(\t.*)(\t.*)@\\1/\2\\2/\3@#' file{b,c} |
sed -rf - filea
```

This builds a sed script from the files other than the first that inserts values matching the key of each line. No sorting is needed other than placing the files in the correct order when building the script. The created script is then piped and run against the first file to obtain the required result.

N.B. the `-s` option allows the header line of each file to be disregared from each daughter file, the parent file will have no match and will be unchanged.

However the question allowed for an unspecified number of columns, this requires a similar but more involved solution:

```
sed -sr '1d;s#[^\t]+#/^&/{#;s#\t([^\t]+)#s@\\t([^\\t]+)@\\n\\1/\1@;#g;s#$#y/\\n/\\t/;}#' file{b,c}|
sed -rf - filea
```

In this solution each tab in the parent/daughter files requires a substitution command (as in the previous solution the backreferences were named and hence limited to 9). Each substitution is closed by removing the tab and replacing it by a newline thus reducing the backreference to one only, the newlines are then replaced at the end by translating them to tabs again.